# Access DB Table - Split Field SQL Command

Tags: sql, ms-access, split, sql-update, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 Database Table,  dbo_GOV

**THE GOAL**

I want to take the USSenators field, which contains data like (below) and split it into USSenator1 and USSenator2 fields, respectively:

```
John Smith;Sarah Levens
Bill Burr;Kevin Nill
George Thomson;Tracy Johnson
```

---

**THE PROBLEM**

I've tried a few different Access SQL queries... both (below) when executed, give the error message

> Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression
>   'Split(USSenators & ";", ';')(0'.

I have verified that there are 0 records, where USSenators is blank.  Every row has 2 people listed, separated by a semicolon.

---

**SQL QUERIES**

```
UPDATE dbo_GOV
SET
    USSenator1 = Split(USSenators & ";",';')(0),
    USSenator2 = Split(USSenators & ";",';')(1);
```

---

```
UPDATE dbo_GOV
SET
   USSenator1 = Split(USSenators,';')(0),
   USSenator2 = Split(USSenators,';')(1);
```

---

I've tried referencing the Office documentation for Split: **[here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-function-HA001228911.aspx)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Split in a query, use Mid and Instr.

```
Mid(USSenators,Instr(USSenators,";")+1)
Mid(USSenators,1,Instr(USSenators,";")-1)
```

Line 2 above returns John Smith for the first record
Line 1 above returns Sarah Levens for the first record

You will need to watch for nulls.

Comment: Seems that Split should be a valid command...?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-function-HA001228911.aspx

Comment: There is a big difference between ACE / Jet (the database, with SQL) and Access (the front end, with VBA)